# Project name contains unsupported characters! Error while exporting signed APK in Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I am getting  "Project name contains unsupported characters!" error while exporting the app since my project name contains a single quote in the name.
But my question is if exporting is not allowed why did it allow me to create the project at first place and second, how can I resolve it without damaging any project resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android package names may only contain letters, numbers and an underscore ('_'). I have no idea how you were able to create an Android project with a package name that has an illegal character (is it possible you changed it in AndroidManifest after you've created the project?)

Fixing this is fairly simple, just rename your package in AndroidManifest and search & replace your old package name with the new one in all of your source files (.java files). If you're using Linux this can be achieved with a simple bash command, if you're on Windows you'll probably have to do this manually.