# Project name contains unsupported characters! Error while exporting signed APK in Android using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am getting "Project name contains unsupported characters!" error while exporting the app since my project name contains ampersand i.e, & in the name. How to resolve these error? Pls help me.
Here is the same problem in this site but there is no solution
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222426/project-name-contains-unsupported-characters-error-while-exporting-signed-apk-i)

Comment: "there is no solution" -- there is an accepted answer on that question. Please explain, completely and precisely, why that accepted answer is not working for you.

Comment: Can't you remove unsupported characters? Don't think there is any other solution

Comment: Just remove the unsupported characters. The answer to the question you linked to lists the characters that you are allowed to use.